# How to stop a flexed div from rezising and overlapping into other elements?

Tags: html, css

I am currently goofing around making a website. I want to make a description div in the center of the screen that will stay centered, and when the screen rezises not stretch up and intersect or overlap other elements. How would I go about this? For further demonstration I will post a video below of what I don't want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1dwo.jpg

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    --link-easing-time: 0.15s;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.overview {
    background-image: url(/Images/1.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.overview div {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
    border-radius: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-basis: initial;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.overview p {
    margin: 1em;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.overview a {
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="overview">
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, inventore sint, nam sunt nihil ipsam quia accusantium praesentium voluptates, fugiat dolorum rerum officia. Nisi aperiam cumque totam molestias earum commodi.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error consectetur dolorem magnam nobis officiis minima facilis vel corrupti totam fugiat tempora alias libero accusamus illo animi delectus, ut nostrum consequatur.
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit excepturi, modi repudiandae ad itaque adipisci ratione a sed, voluptatem, quas aliquam dolore commodi eos possimus dignissimos nobis rerum enim tenetur?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam inventore unde sequi laudantium sapiente, quisquam necessitatibus officia eum autem nihil exercitationem, magni corporis fuga nulla eligendi! Provident explicabo recusandae earum!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis alias molestiae impedit dolores consectetur delectus voluptas saepe nam blanditiis dolorum. Inventore omnis dicta consequatur mollitia magnam! Cum corrupti aspernatur sapiente.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, laborum non. Fugit id inventore, sequi minima explicabo optio at ut, repellat ipsam quia nemo! Libero quidem eaque obcaecati tenetur dolor.
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem sint necessitatibus perferendis tempore quisquam earum ipsa minima, obcaecati dolore. Ut, unde. Mollitia animi assumenda facilis quis dolores provident asperiores!
            </p>
            <a href="" class="hover-effect">
                Learn More
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I attempted messing with `flex-basis:initial` and `flex-wrap: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I re wrote the code and what conclusion I reached was that: the `<p>` tag was effecting the parent div size so once I gave the p tag a height and width containment and set the overflow to hidden it worked great!